# tbb concurrent hash map find & insert

Tags: c++, tbb, concurrenthashmap

I am currently using tbb's concurrent hash map to perform concurrent insertions into a hash map. Each key is a string and a value is a vector of integers. I would like to achieve the following: during insertions, if the key does not exist, I insert it and add the value to its vector. If it exists, I simply add the value to its vector.

After inspecting the tbb concurrent hash map API, I noticed that both the find and insert functions return booleans only. So how can I return a pointer to the key if it exists?

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: Apologies for the delay in marking the right answer. Yes, you did. Thanks for your support. I see that the tbb community is certainly small!

Comment: thanks :) Yes, [tag:tbb] community is pretty small, small number of upvotes, questions, views..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are methods which require an accessor in theirs arguments. The accessor is basically a pointer coupled with a `scoped_lock` protecting concurrent access to the element. Without the lock, an element can be modified concurrently resulting in a data-race. So, never use a pointer to element in concurrent_hash_map directly (unless protected by the accessor).

Also, you don't need a `find()` method for your task since `insert()` methods create the element if it does not exist.

According to the [Reference manual](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_hash_map_cls.htm), the hash map has the following methods which will likely satisfy your needs:

```
bool insert( accessor& result, const Key& key );         // creates new element by default
bool insert( accessor& result, const value_type& value );// creates new element by copying
```

Here is an example:

```
{
    hash_map_t::accessor a;
    hash_map.insert( a, key );       // creates by default if not exists, acquires lock
    a->second.my_vector.push_back( value ); // new or old entry, add to vector anyway
} // the accessor's lock is released here
```

Comment: Is accessor lock a lock on just one record (alike transactional memory) or on whole map (all operations would be locked alike one would do manually with standard std::unordered_map + std::lock)?

Comment: Just one element is locked by the accessor of course. Please note that it is read-write lock, see const_accessor

Answer (score 0):

During insertions, if the key does not exist then key inserted and added the value to its vector.
If it exists, return false and I simply add the value to its vector.

```
{
    hash_map_t::accessor accessor;
   
    bool result = hash_map.insert(accessor, std::make_pair(key, {value})); // creates by default if not exists, acquires lock
    if(result == false)
        accessor->second.push_back(value); // if key exists
} // the accessor's lock is released here
```